# Post Sharepoint 2013 to 2016 Upgrade - Search Broken

Tags: sharepoint

I've recently completed upgrading a Sharepoint 2013 to 2016 upgrade by following the official MS technet guide. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436(v=office.16).aspx) It is a very small single server farm (1 Web App and Site Collection). It is a proof of concept/demo deployment at the moment.

Details:

2013 Farm: Web App Name - Sharepoint-80 URL - http://sp2/

2016 Farm: Web App Name - Sharepoint-80 URL - http://sp16/

It appears to have gone well and I can access the site on the new 2016 farm (via http://sp16). From what I can tell, it is all there and working as it did on the 2013.

The only thing that isn't working at all however is the search function.

When I try to run a search from anywhere on the site I get the following errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GDSb.png

Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or Result Types.

Template '~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Control_SearchBox.js' not found or has syntax errors. (LoadTemplate: )

Any idea why this is happening and how I can correct this? Am I overlooking something?

Thanks,
Oliver.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this, I was able to fix the issue by copying the Display Template files from another site collection using Sharepoint 2013 Designer (works with Sharepoint 2016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by creating a new web application and test site collection and then copying the 'Display Templates' folder from the new site collection to the old/upgraded site collection.

I had to use Sharepoint Designer 2013 (which works with Sharepoint 2016) to do this. I copied the entire folder and let it overwrite all of the original folder's contents.